# writing custom functions that use external java classes on Hive

Tags: hive

I've been thinking of how to do it in Hive.

For e.g. i've a specific field in a log file that I want to extract (this is already possible in Hive) and then I want to map this field's value to something else. This mapping is determiened by own customic business logic that is coded up in a Java Class.
How can I use this Java class in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the instructions here:  [UDF Information](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/HivePlugins) to create a User Defined Function which can be called like substr, count or length.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use

```
add jar  myjar.jar;
```

in the hive script, just as you had done with the jar containing the UDF.  I would recommend packaging them all up in a single jar.